# Rails I18n.load_path add custom files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I have a rails 4.0.2 app which uses I18N. The *config/application.rb* file states that

> the default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.

But when I add *app.en.yml* and *app.fr.yml* to the *config/locales* folder, none of the two files appear in I18n.load_path, unless I add the following line to *config/application.rb*:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join("config", "locales", "app.*.{rb,yml}").to_s]
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's not appeared in your I18n load_path?

Comment: I loaded the rails console and the output from I18n.load_path said so.

Comment: seeems your files has lost after fast Rails reload, i.e. has affected only first time, check loading with "rails c" and ```Rails.configuration.i18n.load_path````

Answer (score 0):

Seems your i18n files may lost after hot-reload by Rails engine, i.e. has affected only first time. You are also able to make sure what files are loaded in Rails console `rails c` as:

`Rails.configuration.i18n.load_path`